# Does swift inheritance from generic class prevent protocol conformance via extension?

Tags: swift

```
@objc public protocol P1 {
  func p1foo()
}

@objc public protocol P2 {
  func p2foo()
}

class A<T>: NSObject, P1 {
  func p1foo() { }
}

class B: A<Int> {

}

extension B: P2 {
  func p2foo() { }
}
```

-> Type 'B' does not conform to protocol 'P2'.

Why? Removing the generic solves this error, but I don't understand - B should be a fully-specific type at this point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the combination of the `@objc` and the generic. Objective-C knows nothing of Swift generics, so your notion that B should adopt an `@objc` protocol causes the compiler to throw a wobbly.

You've already detected this from one direction; and you can equally see it from the other. You can make your code compile by deleting the `@objc` attributes. Or you can make it compile by removing the generic. You can't have both at once.